# Is there a way to connect to existing store instance

Tags: redux-devtools

I want to connect to the existing store instance in development mode to dispatch some actions to simulate the production environment.

I tried using:

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Methods.md#connect

but looks like it is creating a new instance every time. Is there a way to connect to existing store and dispatch an action using API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__.connect()` to connect to an existing instance, you need to know and reuse its `instanceId`. You can set this explicitly on the `connect` options object:

```js
const instanceA = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__.connect({
  instanceId: 1234
});
const instanceB = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__.connect({
  instanceId: 1234
});
```

While `instanceA !== instanceB`, messages you `.send` to `instanceA` and `instanceB` should still end up together in the Redux DevTools extension.